# PhantomJS 2.1.1 : "errorMessage":"Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated

Tags: centos, webdriver, phantomjs

I am using phantomjs with WebDriver for headless testing in Cent OS. phantomjs.exe for Windows is working perfectly. But when I make the jar file for Cent OS, there comes errors like:

```
"errorMessage":"Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
```

or

```
Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
```

I have the below code for making executable jar for Cent OS:

```
@Before
public void setUp()
{               
    logger.info("Inside setup().");
    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);                
    caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, "phantomjs");
    driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    logger.info("Exiting setUP().");
}
```

I just put a try-catch block to understand the thrown error and found that the below code is the reason for the error:

```
public void goToMyPageAfterLogin()
{
    try
    {
        logger.info("Inside goToMyPageAfterLogin().");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li[@id='header-mypage-top']//a")));

        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='header-mypage-top']//a"));
        element.click();
        logger.info("Exiting goToMyPageAfterLogin().");
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

This li element is not being found anyway. But this element is found if I execute the code in a windows environment with phantomjs.exe of version 2.1.1.

Comment: So, you can try another way to locate that li element. Please try to use cssSelector

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using JavaScriptExecutor? http://selenium-solutions.blogspot.in/2012/11/enabling-hidden-element-using.html